# Is It Necessary to Activate Addons to Make Them Work?

Tags: plone

Usually I have to activate my available add-ons in order to make them working. But I find collective.geo.behaviour and my custom transmogrifier package seem working well without activating them. This make me wonder what is the trick behind the scenes. Will something go wrong if I keep using these addons without activating them?

[image: Plone Available Add-ons]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python packages that are installed for use in your Plone environment show up in your add-on list because they have Generic Setup profiles for addition to a Plone environment. *Usually* these profiles do things like set browser layers, add skin layers, add types or setup the catalog. They can also specify that the Generic Setup profile for some other add-on(s) should be run when this package is installed.

The two cases you mention here have different things going on:

1. crgis transmogrifier has a GS profile, but -- as far as I can tell based on examining its repository -- does not need one. It's GS profile does nothing. So, the install add-on choice will do nothing. Drop a note to the add-on author and tell them that.
2. Collective Geo Behavior's GS profile does nothing but specify that a couple of other add-on GS profiles be run. If you have already done the add-on installation for those, then this step does nothing. But, don't rely on that fact for future installations.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because these profiles don't do anything different than declare dependencies and the Code & ZCML are loaded at startup. So as long as you already have imported the dependencies listed in the profile you should be fine.

Also I think you could have packages without a profile, if you don't have a dependency or need to register something.